# how to get Json.net serialize DateTime similar to JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: c#, json.net, javascriptserializer

My code base had been using `JavaScriptSerializer` for long time, now I am planning to migrate to `Json.Net`. I saw that `DateTime` Serializing on both work differently.

```
Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow));

Output:"\/Date(1403629024695)\/"

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow));

Output: "2014-06-24T16:57:04.6954145+00:00"
```

Is there a way to get Json.net to serialize similar to JavaScriptSerializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat`

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, 
                                              new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat }));
```

Comment: Format is different. returns: /Date(1667894400000-0800)/ instead of /Date(1403629024695)/